# EF / TPT / linq query to get previous record by ID generates wrong SQL when entity is selected

Tags: mysql, sql, linq, entity-framework-6, table-per-type

I did the following tests in LinqPAD:

A. loading just the id of an entity.

```
(from s in Set<Sale>() 
 where s.ID < 9000000 
 orderby s.ID descending 
 select s.ID).Take(1)
```

which returns the ID: 8999998 (correct) and optimized (see below)

```
SELECT
   `Extent1`.`ID`
FROM 
   `Sale` AS `Extent1` 
INNER JOIN 
   `Entity` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`ID` = `Extent2`.`ID`
WHERE 
   `Extent1`.`ID` < 9000000
ORDER BY 
   `Extent1`.`ID` DESC LIMIT 1
```

B. loading the whole entity (s.Id become s in the query, there are no other differences)

```
(from s in Set<Sale>() 
 where s.ID < 9000000 
 orderby s.ID descending 
 select s).Take(1)
```

which returns the correct result but it does so by loading the whole data in process (see the SQL below / i removed fields to make it shorter)

```
SELECT
    `Project1`.`C1`, 
    ....
FROM 
    (SELECT
       `Extent1`.`ID`, 
       ..... 
       @gp1 AS `C1`
    FROM 
       `Sale` AS `Extent1` 
    INNER JOIN 
       `CompanyEntity` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`ID` = `Extent2`.`ID` 
    INNER JOIN 
       `Entity` AS `Extent3` ON `Extent1`.`ID` = `Extent3`.`ID`
    WHERE 
       `Extent1`.`ID` < 9000000) AS `Project1`
ORDER BY 
    `Project1`.`ID` DESC LIMIT 1
```

As you can see the `orderby` and `limit` are moved outside the nested query.

My question is: how to make EF generate a decent SQL in the second case ?

Note: using TPT strategy, EF6, MySql (also tested on SQL Server).